# Linking a page of a particular date

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to link a page with a date, which has been updated(page) on a specific date?

```
 $(function(){
    $( "#date-suggestions" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1950:2050"
    });
    });
```

Comment: give default value ? maybe this.. `$("#date-suggestions").val(dateFormat(new Date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));` will give value current date.

Comment: try this site : http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: changeMonth and changeYear is event http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html?highlight=changemonth